# Double negation sql query

Tags: sql, negation

I was asked to do a query in sql using double negation. The question itself is asking for all the "sigla" and "disciplina "where the semestre_id is 21 and has at least 1 attribute "resposta"=5

table
[image: http://i.imgur.com/8CDoFHZ.png]

query
[image: http://i.imgur.com/5aueUKS.png]

Now despite posting all this my question is mostly that I am not too sure if this is the way of doing a proper double negation in sql, since I am getting as an answer all the lines of the table which is wrong. Since I am having an hard time searching for examples online could anyone clarify me?

Comment: you want to _where the semestre_id is 21_ but you selecting where semestre_id is not 21

Comment: I thought I was first selecting those who had resposta 5 then selecting the semestre 21 that don't have resposta 5 and then selecting those that aren't semestre 21 that don't have resposta 5

Comment: your question states AND for the condition. Your comment expresses an exclusive OR. Are you sure of your translation to english?

Comment: My bad I meant " that are semestre 21 that don't have resposta 5" which then the last "not in" would exclude, leaving only those that have resposta 5

Answer (score 1):

```
select  disc.disciplina_id, disc.sigla
from    ipdw_disciplina disc
        inner join ipdw_respostas resp
            on disc.disciplina_id = resp.disciplina_id
where   resp.semestre_id = 21
        and resp.resposta = 5
group by disc.disciplina_id, disc.sigla
```

i try to avoid in / not in whenever possible.  It seems easier to follow the intent of the query without them.  This looks like a pretty straight forward query that does not need the double negation.

Comment: Yes without double negation it would be easier, however the questions explicitly states that I must use double negation.